# Wrap text around an image with css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Im learning css grid and im using it to layout my website, with 4 columns with 2 row. inside each of these columns there is a seperate grid item. one grid item contains text and the other contains an image. When I resize the screen width to around 520px, the grid item containing the text turns into a long column. Is there a way in which the text would wrap around the image

At the moment, I get this when I resize the screen to 520px

[image: Resized screen image in a long column]

Below is a codepen of containing a small sample of my website.

```
https://codepen.io/humzaysf/pen/BaKOxXJ
```

```
<section class="about-us-section section-header">
        <h1 class="about-us-header header-title">
            About Us
        </h1>
</section>

<div class="section-container">
    <div class="section-content history">
        <h4 class="content-sub-title ">
            History
        </h4>
        <p class="content">
            I'm in the shizzle izzle tortor. Fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle we gonna chung rhoncus
            fizzle. In hac get down get down sheezy shut the shizzle up. Break yo neck, yall, mattizzle ac, eleifend
            vitae, nunc. That's the shizzle suscipit. Pimpin' sempizzle that's the shizzle sizzle fo shizzle mah nizzle
            fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle.
        </p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1421809313281-48f03fa45e9f?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=675&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1000" alt="" class="history-image content-image">


    <div class="section-content aims">
        <h4 class="content-sub-title ">
            Aims
        </h4>
        <p class="content">
            I'm in the shizzle izzle tortor. Fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle we gonna chung rhoncus
            fizzle. In hac get down get down sheezy shut the shizzle up. Break yo neck, yall, mattizzle ac, eleifend
            vitae, nunc. That's the shizzle suscipit. Pimpin' sempizzle that's the shizzle sizzle fo shizzle mah nizzle
            fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="section-content quality">
        <h4 class="content-sub-title ">
            Quality
        </h4>
        <p class="content">
            I'm in the shizzle izzle tortor. Fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle we gonna chung rhoncus
            fizzle. In hac get down get down sheezy shut the shizzle up. Break yo neck, yall, mattizzle ac, eleifend
            vitae, nunc. That's the shizzle suscipit. Pimpin' sempizzle that's the shizzle sizzle fo shizzle mah nizzle
            fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle.
        </p>
    </div>
    <img src="assets/images/window/im3rd-media-8-gTweicLAk-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="quality-image content-image">
```

Comment: No, wrapping text around an image requires floats which are not supported in CSS-Grid

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: @Paulie_D any idea how I can achieve this using the existing HTML?

Comment: You can't as it stands.